# Play and stream transcribe audio with python speech_recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am new to Python and trying to figure out on how I can **transcribe an audio speech from file in realtime** with the sound playing along in the background.

Update:

> @petezurich Sorry for the bad question. Currently, I can hear the
>   audio playing in the background. However, I am having trouble getting
>   Sphinx to transcribe the audio. Is there something wrong with the way
>   I am passing the audio to Sphinx?
>   It's constantly outputting "Sphinx error" message.

I am using *PocketSpinx* with the *Uberi/speech_recognition* library.

This is what I have put together so far:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python
# recognitions.py : Transcribe Test from an Audio File

import os
import sys
import time
import wave
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr
import threading

try:
    import pocketsphinx
except:
    print("PocketSphinx is not installed.")

# import audio file within script folder
from os import path
audio_file = path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])), "samples/OSR_us_000_0061_8k.wav")
print("Transcribing... " + audio_file)
wf = wave.open(audio_file, 'rb')

# set PyAudio instance
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
# set recognizer instance (unmodified)
r = sr.Recognizer()

stream_buffer = bytes()
stream_counter = 0
audio_sampling_rate = 48000

def main_recognize(stream):
    global audio_sampling_rate
    # Create a new AudioData instance, which represents "mono" audio data
    audio_data = sr.AudioData(stream, audio_sampling_rate, 2)

    # recognize using CMU Sphinx (en-US only)
    try:
        print("Sphinx: " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio_data, language="en-US"))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Sphinx error")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))

def stream_audio(data):
    global stream_buffer
    global stream_counter

    buffer_set_size = 200

    if stream_counter < buffer_set_size:
        # force 'data' to BYTES to allow concat
        data = bytes()
        stream_buffer += data
        stream_counter += 1
    else:
        threading.Thread(target=main_recognize, args=(stream_buffer,)).start()
        # reset
        stream_buffer = bytes()
        stream_counter = 0


# define callback
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    data = wf.readframes(frame_count)
    stream_audio(in_data)
    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)
# open audio stream
stream = pa.open(format=pa.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)
# start the stream
stream.start_stream()
# wait for stream to finish
while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)
# stop stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
wf.close()
# close PyAudio
pa.terminate()
```

Any advice or recommendation on what might I been doing wrong?

Is my approach heading to the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @petezurich Sorry for the bad question. Currently, I can hear the audio playing in the background. However, I am having trouble getting Sphinx to transcribe the audio. Is there something wrong with the way I am passing the audio to Sphinx?

Answer (score 0):

Uberi wrapper does not work with streams, you should try something like the [original pocketsphinx API](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/python/test/continuous_test.py) instead

```
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')
decoder = Decoder(config)

stream = open(path.join(DATADIR, 'goforward.raw'), 'rb')
#stream = open('10001-90210-01803.wav', 'rb')

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
        if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
            in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
            if not in_speech_bf:
                decoder.end_utt()
                print 'Result:', decoder.hyp().hypstr
                decoder.start_utt()
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The code is based on this project [link](https://github.com/randaller/souncard2txt) which transcribes the input audio from a microphone in realtime and it seems to be working by passing audio buffers to the recognizer. My questions is: Are the streams from microphone different from the wave streams here? @Nikolay Shmyrev

Comment: Streams are the same, the project you linked does not work realtime since it processes fixed big chunks, the code above does.

Comment: Running the complete and unmodified script at [link](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/python/test/continuous_test.py) results in SyntaxError on line 31 and once fixed with 'print (decoder.hyp().hypstr)', resulted RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1.